# Ruby's Eqv for Mathematica's Nest Function?

Tags: ruby, nested

[Here's Mathematica's Nest function Definition](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Nest.html). What's the eqv. in Ruby?

The idea is this:

```
nest(f, x, 3) #=> f(f(f(x)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your own using [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
def nest(f, x, n)
  n.times.inject(x) { |m| f.call(m) }
end
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
>> def f(x) 2*x end
>> nest(method(:f), 1, 3)
=> 8
```

If you want a function back (i.e. leave `x` unspecified) then you could return a lambda:

```
def nestx(f, n)
  ->(x) { n.times.inject(x) { |m| f.call(m) } }
end
```

and use it like this:

```
>> nestx(method(:f), 3).call(1)
=> 8
```

Or you could rearrange the `nest` arguments and use [`Proc#curry`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html#method-i-curry):

```
def nest(f, n, x)
  n.times.inject(x) { |m| f.call(m) }
end

>> method(:nest).to_proc.curry.call(method(:f), 3).call(1)
=> 8
```

You can also use `[]` in place of `call` if want something that looks more like a function call:

```
def nest(f, n, x)
  n.times.inject(x) { |m| f[m] }
end

>> method(:nest).to_proc.curry[method(:f), 3][1]
=> 8
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass multiple arguments? like `nest(method(:f),(x,y), n)` assuming the function can take them? This is solved anyway. Answers the question completely :). Just figured if anyone was interested in Nest they might ask that too.

Comment: @Mr.DemetriusMichael: You could use an Array, `[x,y]`, and hand that Array to `inject`. You could also use a splat in `nest` (`nest(f, n, *x)`) to collect the rest of the arguments into an Array and hand that Array to `inject`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know Ruby, but I looked into the description of the language and wrote the following code..

Let it be your function

```
def func(­x)  
   return sin(x­)
end
```

and let define a nest function

```
def nest(­f, x, n)
    count = 0
    while count­<n
        x = send(f, x)
        count += 1
    end
    return x
end
```

Call it as `nest(:func­, 1, 3)` and result will be `0.67843047736074`

I've compared it with the result on http://www.wolframalpha.com and got the same answer.

Comment: That will work as long as `f` is on the same object that has `nest`, otherwise the `send` won't work. Someone will tell you that you don't need the `return` calls so I'll do it while I'm here. And an iterator of some sort (see [`Enumerable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html)) would be more idiomatic than a `while` loop.

Comment: @muistooshort Sorry, but I do not know Ruby :)

Comment: But now you do know some Ruby, so there :)

Comment: @muistooshort  I do not know it well enough. The problem is that I'm using so many languages at the same time that it takes some period of time to switch from one to another. And a little more time to learn the nuances of the new language. I'm a physicist, not a programmer :) Thanks for the comment.